# Does `execve()` set up registers to invoke dynamic linker or the executable to be executed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dynamic-linking, exec

*Understanding the Linux Kernel* says `execve()` calls `load_binary()` of each `linux_binfmt` object, and `load_binary()`

> Invokes the start_thread( ) macro to modify the values of the User Mode registers eip and esp saved on the Kernel Mode stack, so that they point to the **entry point of the dynamic linker** and to the top of the new User Mode stack, respectively.

[mosvy wrote:](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498347/674)

> What happens is that the kernel arranges for the `execve` system call, upon returning to user mode, to have the IP (instruction pointer) register set to point to **the beginning of the `_start` function**, and the SP (stack pointer) register set to point to the beginning of the argv + env string list, so the effect from the point of view of user mode is as if someone had called the `_start` function as:
>
> ```
> _start(argc, argv0, argv1, ... , NULL, env0, env1, ... NULL)
> ```
>
> in a calling convention where all arguments are passed on the stack.

By "the beginning of the `_start` function", did  he mean  **the  entry point of the executable to be executed**?

Which one is correct? I.e. does `execve()` set up registers to invoke dynamic linker or the executable to be executed?

Comment: What distinction is this question drawing between _the executable to be executed_ and _the dynamic linker_, given that that is the executable to be executed?

Comment: The  distinction  between the executable to be executed and the dynamic linker. You need to load and invoke dynamic linker to load shared libraries needed by the executable, before executing the executable.

Comment: So you are ignoring what the answers to your questions at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448937/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476780/ both told you.

Comment: I am not. I am asking for explicit explanation to my questions.

Comment: They're really the same.  IP always set to the entry point of a final loader/dynamic linker/interpretor of scripts/whatever name you like to call. Depends on what core function of a program provides, you name it. But name never needs be meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

_start is the entry point of an executable. In C you may think that main is the entry point, but this is just the point of view of the programmer. The compiler may insert other code in _start, to run before calling main.

My interpretation is that everything described in you question, happens before calling _start (or seeming to call _start).

Comment: Might be better not to say that. Kernel doesn't care about _start but e_entry defined in ELF header. Although compiler love to make them the same.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 even the psABI refers to `_start` ;-) (see section 3.4.1).